# Is there an effective way to calculate runtime complexity in the algorithm of java code?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I am practicing algorithm and data structures, I was wondering if there is an effective way of calculating algorithm and data structures in the Java code? Such as being able to system.out.println the speed of my algorithm? Thanks.

Comment: Runtime speed and algorithmic complexity are two different things. Which are you asking about?

Comment: Perhaps this is a troll? It's a wonderful, paradoxical, classical result of computer science that there is no effective procedure for determining the asymptotic run time of an arbitrary algorithm. Indeed, there's not even a way to determine if an arbitrary algorithm terminates at all. The best we can do is find proofs of the run times (or failure to terminate) of a useful subset. Consequently, the answer to your question is "absolutely not."

Answer (score 1):

First thing your question is not very clear and one can easily find the worst case time complexity by looking at the pseudo-code of your algorithm but still if you want to know the exact amount of time that your algorithm took, here is one approach that you can try out.

1. Get the time at the starting of your algorithm.
2. Get the time at the end of your algorithm.
3. Now take the difference between them and it will give you the amount of time your program took to run.

Now keep on increasing the value N (N here is the value on which your algorithm depends).

Now you can plot a graph between N vs time taken and from the graph you can get an idea about the worst case time complexity of your algorithm.

Hope this helps!